# simple php page: what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: php, lamp

using Eclipse 3.5.2 (PDT, WEB TOOLS , APTANA 2 and debugging with XDEBUG) on UBUNTU 10.04...

I can not figure out for the life of me what is wrong with this code.  I've been working for years as a .NET developer, so I think I know how to read documentation and configure a basic app although I'm new to LAMP.

The following page only displays the "PHP is Running" and the first list of "me", "you" and "her".  I've double checked the db credentials by logging into PhpMyAdmin.

When debugging and I step into core_db.php, the variables are all listed as `<Uninitialized>` and everything stops at the line `$stmt->execute();`

**list_users.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<?php include 'db/chore_db.php' ?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=encoding">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo 'Php is running'; ?>
<ul>
<?php $ar = array('me','you','her');
foreach ($ar as $user) {
    ?>
    <li><?php   echo $user;}?></li>
</ul>

<div>

<?php 
$db = new chore_db();
$myusers = $db->get_users(null,null);

foreach ($myusers as $u) {
    ?>


<ul>
    <li><?php echo $u;  }?></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**chore_db.php**

```
<?php    
class chore_db{
    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @param string $user_name
     * @return Ambigous <multitype:, usersTbl>
     */
    public function  get_users($id, $user_name){
        $users = array();
        $sql = '';
        $con = null;


        $sql = 'SELECT id, chore_type, name, description, created_dt, created_by, modified_dt, modified_by FROM chores';// where id = IFNULL(?,id) and name = IFNULL(?,name)";
        $con = new mysqli('localhost','chore_admin','!chore_admin','chores');

        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

        //bind parameters
        //$stmt->bind_param('ss', $id_param, $name_param);
        //$id_param = $id;
        //$name_param = $user_name;
        //execute the sql

        $stmt->execute();

        //now bind the results to variables
        $stmt->bind_result($rs_id, $rs_chore_type, $rs_name, $rs_description, $rs_created_dt, $rs_created_by, $rs_modified_dt, $rs_modified_by);

        while($stmt->fetch()){
            $users[] = new usersTbl($rs_id, $rs_chore_type, $rs_name, $rs_description, $rs_created_dt, $rs_created_by, $rs_modified_dt, $rs_modified_by);

        }

        return $users;
    }
}



class usersTbl{
    public $id;
    public $user_name;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;
    public $created_dt;
    public $created_by;
    public $modified_dt;
    public $modified_by;

    public $user_chore_list;
    public $user_chore_date_list;

    //public function __construct(){}
    public function __construct($userId, $uName, $fName, $lName, $createdDT, $createdDT, $createdBY, $modifiedDT, $modifiedBy){
        $this->id = $userId;
        $this->user_name = $uName;
        $this->first_name = $fName;
        $this->last_name = $lName;
        $this->created_by = $createdBY;
        $this->created_dt = $createdDT;
        $this->modified_by = $modifiedBy;
        $this->modified_dt = $modifiedDT;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where have you saved your document? Can you access it via http://localhost/list_users.php?

Comment: alexn, damn! that was quick. Yes it is [link]http://localhost/Chores/list_users.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=13144807200443[/link]

Comment: @kevcoder Is the end of the HTML output (if your view source)? Or does the output just stop after the list? Also, your list is output wrong in the foreach, you need to close it (the foreach) after the `</li>`, not after the `echo` - this goes for both loops/lists.

Comment: also the project is saved at /var/www/Chores and my account is owner of everything under /var/www

Comment: also, what do you get if you `var_dump($myusers);`?

Comment: What do you actually want to output in the second list? A set of HTML tables or just one column from the result or what?

Comment: Can you post what error you are getting?  `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` if you haven't set that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul>
<?php $ar = array('me','you','her');
foreach ($ar as $user) {
    ?>
    <li><?php   echo $user;}?></li>  <<< this is at least one of the problems
</ul>
```

Comment: that was it! Both of the loops had the same problem.  once I corrected it (and the sql: it was actually not looking at the users table), I'm seeing output.  Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to echo objects, without giving any indication of how their contents should be formatted. You should still be getting some output, so there is obviously something else going on, but here is a version with many issue fixed:

**list_users.php**

```
<?php include 'db/chore_db.php' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=encoding">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php echo 'Php is running'; ?>
    <ul>
      <?php 
        $ar = array('me','you','her');
        foreach ($ar as $user) {
      ?>
      <li><?php echo $user; ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <?php 
          $db = new chore_db();
          $myusers = $db->get_users(null,null);
          foreach ($myusers as $u) {
        ?>
        <li><?php echo $u->user_name; ?></li> <!-- You need to echo a property of the object (or several, rather than the object itself... -->
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did catch that as well.  But why am I not seeing any errors thrown to the page?

Comment: Depends on your error level/display settings (see afuzzyllama's comment on the question) but it's not always an error to print/echo an object. You may get a 'Catchable Fatal Error...' but you may also get a string like 'Object(classname)#1', depending on many many factors. It's worth checking your Apache logs, as errors will probably show up there even if they don't show up in the output...

Comment: OK. Also you asked about the PHP file ending with a `?>`.  why don't PHP files created with eclipse include the closing `?>`?

Comment: @kevcoder Don't remember asking about that, but: You are not required to include a closing `?>`, depending on what you are doing in the file. Anything outside `<?php ?>` is treated as direct output, as you have used it above, but if you were to create a file that is pure PHP (like *chore_db.php*) you don't need to include it, and there is an argument that it is better to leave it out. This is because it helps avoice problems where you have extra whitespace in one of these files that have been included. This white-space could be sent to the browser, and stop you from using `header()` later on.